# $.ajax statusCode function never receive parameters

Tags: ajax, jquery, http-status-codes

According to the [official jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) :

> If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as the error callback.

But in fact, it's not. With this code :

```
    function saveCampagne (data){
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : "GET",
            data : data,
            statusCode:{
                201 : function(campagne){
                    // JSON Decode
                    var Campagne = JSON.parse(campagne);
                    $("#zone-message").append('<div class="alert fade in" data-alert="alert"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a><p><strong>C\'est Fait !</strong> La campagne a été ajoutée sous la référence #'+Campagne.id+'. Elle sera validée prochainement par un administrateur.</p></div>');
                    return Campagne;
                },
                200 : function(){
                    $("#zone-message").append('<div class="alert alert-error fade in" data-alert="alert"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a><p><strong>Woops !</strong> Une erreur est survenue dans la création de la nouvelle campagne. Merci de ré-essayer ultérieurement.</p></div>');
                }
            },
            success : function(campagne){
            },
            error : function(){
                $("#zone-message").append('<div class="alert alert-error fade in" data-alert="alert"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a><p><strong>Woops !</strong> Une erreur est survenue dans la création de la nouvelle société. Merci de ré-essayer ultérieurement.</p></div>');
            }
        });
    }
```

i'm able to make the `.append` but the function never get data (passed through campagne, like `success` ) in my `201 : function(campagne){...}`

Any Idea why it's not working like the doc say how it's works ?

Comment: Use something like firebug to check that the `201` response actually contains data .... im guessing that only a response of `200`/`success` will return data

Comment: 201 response contain the entire object created including the id in the system . It's how the api i request work. Moreover passing parameter on success work too (cause success is status code 2XX)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the success and error handlers.

Comment: I can use error but yes success is raised when satus code is in 2XX range